# How to pass NSMutable Array from one class to another class?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

In ClassObj.h

```
@interface ClassObj : NSObject
{
     NSMutableArray *myArray;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *myArray;
```

In ClassObj.m

```
- (void) display
{
    myAppDelegate *appDelegate = (myAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if (sqlite3_open([[appDelegate getDBPath] UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        const char *sql = "select ID, title from Table";
        sqlite3_stmt *selectstmt;

        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &selectstmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) 
        {
            myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; //inits the new array

            while(sqlite3_step(selectstmt) == SQLITE_ROW) 
            {
                NSInteger primaryKey = sqlite3_column_int(selectstmt, 0);
                ClassObj *myObj = [[ClassObj alloc] initWithPrimaryKey:primaryKey];
                ClassObj.title = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 1)];
                [myArray addObject:myObj];
                [ClassObj release];

            }
        }
    }    
    else
    {
        sqlite3_close(database);
    }
}
```

In TableViewController.m

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    ClassObj * myArray = [[ClassArray alloc] init];

    NSLog(@"myArray count : %d", ClassObj.myArray.count);
    return ClassObj.tagArray.count;
}
```

I'm trying to pass a mutable array from the class object to a TableViewContorller class. But apparently mutable array that I'm trying to retrieve always give 0 value.
Anyone can help? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It gives you 0 object because you are making new object of the class. if you are using navigation controller then you need to get the object from stack see this.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    ClassObj *obj =  (ClassObj *)[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:([self.navigationController.viewControllers count]-2)];

    NSLog(@"myArray count : %d", obj.myArray.count);
    return obj.myArray.count;
}
```

otherwise make an object of `ClassObj` as property in other class and give the reference of the ClassObj when switching to next view and by using this property access the array.

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Tag tagArray]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a62de0'
*** This error occur when I used this code.

Comment: @StilesCrisis Need to make some checks then it is definitely safe.

Comment: In other words, it's not safe as written? :P

Answer (score 0):

Not a big deal, just refer to the basics of passsing the ojects from one class to another.i.e

create the object of ClassObj class & then access the variables & objects using the . property.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    ClassObj * classObj = [[ClassObj alloc] init]; //Make the object of the class

    NSLog(@"%@",classObj. myArray); // Access the variable & objects using .property


    return ClassObj.tagArray.count;
}
```

Now just check below code  & make sure of synthesizing your array in same class, to enable it accessing in another class getting rid of warnings :

```
- (void) display
{
    myAppDelegate *appDelegate = (myAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if (sqlite3_open([[appDelegate getDBPath] UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        const char *sql = "select ID, title from Table";
        sqlite3_stmt *selectstmt;

        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &selectstmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) 
        {
            myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; **//inits the new array**

            while(sqlite3_step(selectstmt) == SQLITE_ROW) 
            {
                NSInteger primaryKey = sqlite3_column_int(selectstmt, 0);
                ClassObj *myObj = [[ClassObj alloc] initWithPrimaryKey:primaryKey];
                ClassObj.title = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 1)];
                [myArray addObject:myObj];
                [ClassObj release];

            }
        }
    }    
    else
    {
        sqlite3_close(database);
    }
**//Print your Array over here ,to make sure of getting objects added to array.**

}
```

Comment: Make sure you intilize and put the objects in the array

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
ClassObj * myArray = [[ClassArray alloc] init];
 //added this line  
[myArray display];
NSLog(@"myArray count : %d", ClassObj.myArray.count);
return ClassObj.tagArray.count;
```

}

Comment: it's work! I get the number of row. But how do I display my data into the table view if I'm using this? The array consist of ID, Title. How do i get the title out and display it in the table view?

Comment: ohh it okay. I figured it out. Thank you so much for your help!:)

Answer (score 0):

Better way return your array when you calling method of particular class.
Your code will be,

```
- (NSMutableArray *) display
{
NSMutableArray *myArray = [NSMutableArray array];

myAppDelegate *appDelegate = (myAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

if (sqlite3_open([[appDelegate getDBPath] UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    const char *sql = "select ID, title from Table";
    sqlite3_stmt *selectstmt;

    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &selectstmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) 
    {
        myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; //inits the new array

        while(sqlite3_step(selectstmt) == SQLITE_ROW) 
        {
            NSInteger primaryKey = sqlite3_column_int(selectstmt, 0);
            ClassObj *myObj = [[ClassObj alloc] initWithPrimaryKey:primaryKey];
            ClassObj.title = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 1)];
            [myArray addObject:myObj];
            [ClassObj release];

        }
    }
}    
else
{
    sqlite3_close(database);
}

return [myArray retain];
```

}

At in your class where u calling this method,

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
     [super viewDidLoad];

// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

objYourArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; 

objOfDatabaseClass = [[YourDatabaseClass alloc] init];  

_tableDataArray = [objOfDatabaseClass display];

//load your tableView
```

}